# В Spring-приложении не инициализируются поля

Tags: java, spring, lombok

Вопрос относится только к полям `name` and `lastName`;

Имеется класс `User`, от которого у меня наследуется класс `Customer`. Соответственно поля родительского класса выдают `null`. Конструктор класса `Customer` имеет `super`.
USER:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    public User(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    User(String name, String lastName){ // Базовый конструктор для дочерних классов
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Поля
    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    @Override
    public String toString() { // Без этого метода вместо инициализированных строк выводятся символы.
        return "User{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    // Методы
    public void changePassword(){// Сменить пароль

    }
}
```

CUSTOMER:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Customer extends User {

    public Customer(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Customer(String name, String lastName){ // Пользовательский конструктор создается,
        super(name, lastName);                     // когда нам нужно создать новый экземпляр,
    }                                              // но у нас еще нет ID.


    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private double wallet;

//    private List<Order> orderList; 


    // Методы
    public void depositMoney(){// Внести деньги на счет

        }

    public void withdrawMoney(){// Вывести деньги со счета

        }

    public void makeOrder(){// Сделать заказ

        }
}
```

В данном классе я передаю данные в конструктор класса `Customer`:
LoadDatabase:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Customer;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(CustomerRepository repository) { // Добавляю данные для Customer
        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Customer("Artur", "Vartanyan")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Customer("Andrey", "Chekmaryov")));
        };
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли приложения выдает:

```java
C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.12.Final\7813daed21576920450443097d69823245d112d2\hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\5528bc882ea499a09d720b42af11785c4fc6be2a\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jvnet.staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\78011e483a21102fb4858f3e8f269a677e50aa23\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.xml.bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\8d49996a4338670764d7ca4b85a1c4ccf7fe665d\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\d6a97364045aa6b99bf2d3c566a3f98599c2d296\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\99f53adba383cb1bf7c3862844488574b559621f\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\8f6ea5daedc614f07a3654a455660145286f024e\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\c4179d48720a1e87202115fbed6089bdc4195405\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.5.RELEASE\d2310c79bebfbc6d66ddeefda102b229d8ae7010\spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.4.RELEASE\bb8391580800110f7a862eac8d399bb88d805405\spring-aspects-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.5.RELEASE\2372fa6c9c638b501961152d84d89427b456fe43\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.5.RELEASE\76d095b5fb1379e443eb90d0d47ef3ebbcbc5448\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.5.RELEASE\716704d3defa9a14d82f98c878b6a5d708f35ee2\spring-boot-starter-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.freemarker\freemarker\2.3.29\46005eeee02e4458520c85d0bcf5001467b053c3\freemarker-2.3.29.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context-support\5.2.4.RELEASE\8ccf5b59f24470200a69717876dc39bcd2c4bca2\spring-context-support-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.11.RELEASE\de7bf0adf13b5e9c4811f95edf18279da193c0c6\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf.extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\36e7175ddce36c486fff4578b5af7bb32f54f5df\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.5.RELEASE\3c1107e2cccfed5d9d34b7ef8cab30375cbbb042\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.4.RELEASE\adad02f679b012c603c9e41757c948ebecae8a32\spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.2.4.RELEASE\69936c9f180a89ecaa0f750cf2121c6f728eec2c\spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.5.RELEASE\aa00f6f95b25353d8e18b66210228a3a8ba29c4\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.2.5.RELEASE\3cfc7b002e7c47f96298df953142719a67863998\spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.2.4.RELEASE\acb068439d37a42006abad2b63511dd4491d80f5\spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.2.4.RELEASE\9ed5335191b9bc8422ec44a90e34d00ee6d737be\spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.5\1740dc9140103b796d1722668805fd4cf852780c\aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.2\57128550e21a83cd1dbf7e82d343b8fbe1f435b\HikariCP-3.4.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.2.4.RELEASE\ec494ddece516d80e7d1f21fe7e6d7c15288392e\spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.4.RELEASE\d67b040b9aa8e917c689c25116f43d973dcceb98\spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\700aeedc4a2089816621948f0379e17cbd17d5db\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.18.Final\7fd00bcd87e14b6ba66279282ef15efa30dd2492\hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\40fd4d696c55793e996d1ff3c475833f836c2498\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\d7466fc2e3af7c023e95c510f06448ad29b225b3\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.8\df457a421493f9de0acb16c4c4c0a62e8f5dd3a3\byte-buddy-1.10.8.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.1.1.Final\c89aa5564fea8b08b9b41f0bbcabb8fed0d89c0d\jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\3fe0bed568c62df5e89f4f174c101eab25345b6c\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\3dce5dbb3571aa820c677fadd8349bfa8f00c199\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.2.5.RELEASE\30b29f1795da75ba864b014db64665de26e5e8\spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.2.4.RELEASE\64442156b13d582c0ca9788753ffcc594b88de0a\spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.2.4.RELEASE\fc5b50a647f319f9ca6ab272177f6d8188bfdfe5\spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.2.4.RELEASE\e657cca52e09ec92c5f5f78cc45591e570fda0a\spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.2.4.RELEASE\155344a8b1a5e98c03c0a102b2aa008d2178f7a1\spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.11.RELEASE\628ebb91f520053d4120b7b18bf78ff295d57461\thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.5.RELEASE\7ff2a903faad06a64429dd1fbba23d7ee653b3a9\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\dfb42ea8ce1a399bcf7218efe8115a0b7ab3788a\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.30\d58bebff8cbf70ff52b59208586095f467656c30\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.30\b5a4b6d16ab13e34a88fae84c35cd5d68cac922c\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.10.2\dca8c8ab85eaabefe021e2f1ac777f3a6b16a3cb\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.10.2\8d95d3f2b20c7d2f598b6d5e7f4e2d688ac1bc78\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.10.2\d380777656dfdd253d9cf0956d61d98dce02c740\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\8b6e01ef661d8378ae6dd7b511a7f2a33fae1421\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.10.2\528de95f198afafbcfb0c09d2e43b6e0ea663ec\jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.31\b6d6013a37e76c2faada9fc8b8c0be6694de5c71\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.31\1e2adb1ea4f2464062ded86b095adf11dc488877\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.31\98ac82f9ad878fa091b94bba0dcd53e98ee03f30\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.31.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\jakarta.validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\5eacc6522521f7eacb081f95cee1e231648461e7\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\ce5be7da2e442c25ec14c766cb60cb802741727b\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.xml.fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\4eb6a0adad553bf759ffe86927df6f3b848c8bea\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.4.RELEASE\a516f6c15db9024ae64ad8aed76232aa3f875f9f\spring-jcl-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\a93ad36df9560de3a5312c1d14f69d938099fa64\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\7b90360afb2b860e09e8347112800d12c12b2a13\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.10.2\3a13b6105946541b8d4181a0506355b5fae63260\jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.10.2\73d4322a6bda684f676a2b5fe918361c4e5c7cca\jackson-core-2.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.projectlombok\lombok\1.18.12\48e4e5d60309ebd833bc528dcf77668eab3cd72c\lombok-1.18.12.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Артур\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\a55e6d987f50a515c9260b0451b4fa217dc539cb\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar" com.tinychiefdelights.TinyChiefDelightsApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-18 21:21:47.910  INFO 5240 --- [           main] c.t.TinyChiefDelightsApplication         : Starting TinyChiefDelightsApplication on LAPTOP-5TNNRU08 with PID 5240 (D:\JetBrainsProjects\TinyChiefDelights\build\classes\java\main started by Артур in D:\JetBrainsProjects\TinyChiefDelights)
2020-03-18 21:21:47.914  INFO 5240 --- [           main] c.t.TinyChiefDelightsApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-18 21:21:48.976  INFO 5240 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-18 21:21:49.056  INFO 5240 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 69ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-18 21:21:49.659  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-18 21:21:49.669  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-18 21:21:49.669  INFO 5240 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-18 21:21:49.833  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-18 21:21:49.833  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1856 ms
2020-03-18 21:21:49.969  INFO 5240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-18 21:21:50.073  INFO 5240 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-18 21:21:50.120  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-18 21:21:50.191  INFO 5240 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-18 21:21:50.313  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-18 21:21:50.429  INFO 5240 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-03-18 21:21:51.069  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-18 21:21:51.076  INFO 5240 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-18 21:21:51.383  WARN 5240 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-18 21:21:51.506  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-18 21:21:51.656  WARN 5240 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-03-18 21:21:51.736  WARN 5240 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.f.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration    : Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] (please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
2020-03-18 21:21:51.827  INFO 5240 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-18 21:21:51.831  INFO 5240 --- [           main] c.t.TinyChiefDelightsApplication         : Started TinyChiefDelightsApplication in 4.37 seconds (JVM running for 5.658)
2020-03-18 21:21:51.896  INFO 5240 --- [           main] com.tinychiefdelights.LoadDatabase       : Preloading User{name='Artur', lastName='Vartanyan'}
2020-03-18 21:21:51.898  INFO 5240 --- [           main] com.tinychiefdelights.LoadDatabase       : Preloading User{name='Andrey', lastName='Chekmaryov'}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: он есть в buld.gradle

Comment: а где именно? на какую строку

Comment: '2020-03-18 21:21:51.896  INFO 5240 --- [           main] com.tinychiefdelights.LoadDatabase       : Preloading User{name='Artur', lastName='Vartanyan'}
2020-03-18 21:21:51.898  INFO 5240 --- [           main] com.tinychiefdelights.LoadDatabase       : Preloading User{name='Andrey', lastName='Chekmaryov'}' Почему он тут все выводит? и инициализирует?

Comment: попробовал без ломбока. Все так же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JPA поля родительской сущности по умолчанию не наследуются: в таблице `Customer` не будет полей `login`, `password`, `name`, `lastName`. Здесь необходимо дать подсказку JPA, и в родительской сущности явно указать [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)